# Postgres faced with: error collation does not exist. when try to change collation

Tags: postgresql, docker

I use docker image for postgres

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
        - '5432:5432'
    container_name: 'postgresql'
    working_dir: /app
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        LC_COLLATE: 'sv_SE.UTF-8'
        LC_CTYPE: 'sv_SE.UTF-8'
    volumes:
        - ./data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./postgres/locale.conf:/etc/locale.conf
    networks:
        - php
```

I want to set swedish collate to my column `category_name` in `category` table, For that I just try to execute this query

```
ALTER TABLE category ALTER COLUMN category_name SET DATA TYPE character varying(255) COLLATE "sv_SE.UTF-8"

> ERROR:  collation "sv_SE.UTF-8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

after that I executed manually in my container

```
root@95494dd4339b:/app# locale-gen sv_SE.utf8 && dpkg-reconfigure locales
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_COLLATE = "sv_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8",
    LC_CTYPE = "sv_SE.UTF-8 UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.utf8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring locales
-------------------

Locales are a framework to switch between multiple languages and allow users to
use their language, country, characters, collation order, etc.

Please choose which locales to generate. UTF-8 locales should be chosen by
default, particularly for new installations. Other character sets may be useful
for backwards compatibility with older systems and software.

  1. All locales
```

Locales to be generated: 1

and choice 1 and after loading all locales I saw

```
416 sv_SE.UTF-8
Default locale for the system environment: 416
```

but after that still faced with the same error

```
> ERROR:  collation "sv_SE.UTF-8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

when I check `pg_collation` I did not found my sv_SE.UTF-8

```
myuser=# SELECT * FROM pg_collation;
  collname  | collnamespace | collowner | collencoding | collcollate | collctype

------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------
--
 default    |            11 |        10 |           -1 |             | 
 C          |            11 |        10 |           -1 | C           | C
 POSIX      |            11 |        10 |           -1 | POSIX       | POSIX
 C.UTF-8    |            11 |        10 |            6 | C.UTF-8     | C.UTF-8
 en_US      |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf
8
 en_US.utf8 |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf
8
 ucs_basic  |            11 |        10 |            6 | C           | C
(7 rows)

myuser=#
```

how to set swedish collate for my column ?

**UPDATE**

after manually executed in postgres container `locale-gen sv_SE.utf8 && dpkg-reconfigure` have that result:

```
root@95494dd4339b:/app# locale -a | grep sv_SE
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
sv_SE
sv_SE.iso88591
sv_SE.iso885915
sv_SE.utf8
```

I try to create new database but faced with the same error... what wrong ??

```
myuser=# CREATE DATABASE test WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'sv_SE.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'sv_SE.UTF-8';
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "sv_SE.UTF-8"
myuser=#
```

```
SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_name COLLATE "sv_SE";
```

but still faced with error `> ERROR:  collation "sv_SE" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist`

maybe need reload service or something like that for apply changes?

Comment: What is the output of `locale -a | grep sv_SE` ? In your Docker setup, do you create the PostgreSQL instance with initdb ?

Comment: I updated my question. I use docker-compose with exist image `image: postgres:9.6`. I did `locale-gen sv_SE.utf8 && dpkg-reconfigure locales` manually, maybe it should be in Dockerfile. I have exist db, which I created before. My goal set new collate to column `category_name` adn if it's possible `convert` exist data

Answer (score 1):

If possbile try to  run `initdb` so that PostgreSQL takes into account available collations (but you need to re-create the database)

or

try to create the collation in the existing PostgreSQL instance with:

```
 create collation swedish (locale='sv_SE.utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create your own docker image like that:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
RUN localedef -i sv_SE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias sv_SE.UTF-8
ENV LANG sv_SE.utf8
```

Do you use a volume to store your database outside your image? If so, you can build a new image, and run it by using the same volume as before and your data should be here.

Comment: I did it, local is swedish it's true, but collate not available: `testuser=# SELECT * FROM hello ORDER BY m COLLATE "sv_SE";
ERROR:  collation "sv_SE" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
RAD 1: SELECT * FROM hello ORDER BY m COLLATE "sv_SE";
                                      ^
testuser=#`